# Proxy configuration on ubuntu 20.04 is not owrking

Tags: network-manager, proxy

I have set a proxy config on the network manager UI and the OS is not even requiring authentication. I know for sure that the config is right as it is the same I'm using on firefox to connect to internet

The problem is that the os is not using this config at all as I am using chrome using the system proxy and I haven't internet on chrome, though I have internet on firefox usng the firefox own proxy with the same configuration.

I have also run from console `wget www.google.com` , and nothing is gotten.  [image].

Comment: can you elaborate ... what is not working ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 I have updated with a more elaborated question could you verify it again please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the same parameter for HTTPS and FTP .

And after you need to restart .

Open a terminal and check you env variables .

```
export | grep -i proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem. I'd like to say connect-proxy also isn't working for me. You could try that, but I haven't had any luck.